# How to unit test service that is using PetaPoco.Database

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks, petapoco

I am using [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) on my current project as a micro ORM and i must say that i like it. However, i found myself struggling with simple scenario - unit testing services that use **PetaPoco.Database**

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly PetaPoco.Database _database;

    public MyService(PetaPoco.Database database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }

    public void SaveSomething(MyObject myObject)
    {
        //...custom logic
        _database.Save(myObject);
    }
}
```

I am using **IoC** (Castle.Windsor) for injection of both **IMyService** and **PetaPoco.Database** wherever needed.

Now, when i try to unit test my service i am unable to properly mock stub **PetaPoco.Database** in order to verify that the **Save** method was properly invoked.
I am using **NUnit** and **Rhino.Mocks** for unit testing and mocking.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyServiceTests
{ 

    private PetaPoco.Database _database;

    [SetUp] 
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _database = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Database>("");
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldProperlySaveSomething()
    {
        //Arrange
        var myObject = new MyObject();
        _database.Expect(db => db.Save(Arg<MyObject>.Is.Anything));
        var myService = new MyService(_database);

        //Act
        myService.SaveSomething(myObject);

        //Assert
        _database.VerifyAllExpectations();   
    }

}
```

I am aware that this can be solved if i extract an Interface from **PetaPoco.Database** and do the mocking against it, or by virtualizing PetaPoco's methods that i want to mock, but the point is that i don't want to make changes to **PetaPoco** at all.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My branch located here: https://github.com/schotime/PetaPoco already has an interface defined for the Database class.

Also there is my new Fork https://github.com/schotime/NPoco or NPoco on nuget which has the same api.

I would use one of these. ;)

Comment: Great job @Schotime, that's exactly what i needed! I am curious though, have you tried to create pull requests to the original codebase?

Comment: Many a time, but I have lots more features as a part of the library now, with lots of bug fixes so they're almost two separate now.

Comment: Is all features of petapoco supported(such as templates) or is there stuff missing? It seems like your fork also does what this plugin does PetaPoco.RelationExtensions. Are you using the same code? I am wondering as you don't see to have any documentation on some of your features so hoping I can use examples from other existing plugins.

Comment: @chobo2 What documentation do you need? I have started some here: https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/wiki

Comment: I don't see any documentation for any of the items in the extra section.

Comment: @chobo2 so what doco do you need and I'll start with it.

Comment: I am not getting how to One-to-Many query helpers. If you could start with this that would be great.

Comment: @Schotime - I see you also wrote PetaPoco.RelationExtensions extension. Has this been merged with npoco?

Comment: @Schotime - See my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019625/how-to-use-npoco-fetchonetomany for the problems I am having with it

Comment: Yes...it has been merged with NPoco

Answer (score 1):

You are already abstracting interactions with PetaPoco.Database using the IMyService interactions, so why do you need another abstraction for? With your current approach you should be able to test interactions with the database using IMyService, e.g.

```
public class AuthenticationService 
{
    private IMyService myService;

    public AuthenticationService(IMyService service) 
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
       var user = myService.GetUser(username); // <-- Hits the database
    }
}
```

and to test it you just mock interactions using a mock/stub of IMyService.

Now regarding your original solution, if PetaPoco public methods are not virtual, I'd fork it, fix the code and send them a pull request. Otherwise, your approach looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Hadi. The point i am asking this question lies in the fact that i want to test MyService business logic in isolation, i.e. i do not want to hit the database, and at the same time i want to assure that database calls are triggered through PetaPoco. The way i see it, this is only possible by mocking **PetaPoco.Database**.

Comment: Forking the code, on the other hand seem like a good solution to me, i might give it a try.